# Heating an ideal under constant pressure

Tags: gas-laws

> To what Celsius temperature must a gas sample initially at $\pu{−20 {^\circ}C}$ be heated if its volume is to double while its pressure remains the same?

What I've tried: first of all change to Kelvin, then I figured this out $V_1/T_1=2V_2/(2T_2)$

Since its volume is doubled so the temperature should be doubled. Am I right? The answer is supposed to be 233.

Comment: You seem to already have your answer, to double the volume you need to double the temperature (in Kelvin). Then just convert back to celsius.

Answer (score 1):

You're *almost* right.  You applied the gas laws properly, but ... You must include units in your answer.  You need 233 °C not just 233.  You may also want to include intermediate steps where you convert the temperature to absolute temperature and tgen double it, the teacher may look for that to grade your understanding of the problem.